# Prevent Firefox Download Pop-up from stealing focus

Tags: firefox

The download popup that asks you where to download (a necessary option for me, as I do not download everything to the same folder) steals focus. So when I am just typing something while it pops up, my typing continues and overwrites the name of the file. I then have to quit the download and start it again to get the file name back. (Ctrl+Z doesn't work in that pop-up.)

Is there a way to configure Firefox to disable this focus-stealing behavior?

Comment: The time between clicking on a download link and the appearance of the dialog is short enough. How come you're already typing elsewhere?

Comment: Run firefox in a VM.

Comment: I believe that is windows behavior, not firefox per se. the dialog that opens is a component of the windows OS, and FF just invokes it.

Comment: @harrymc depending on the site and size of the download the interval can be as long as seven minutes.

Comment: @FrankThomas I'm using Linux, but Firefox behaves that way in Windows as well.

Answer (score 0):

Pop up to ask a question steals focus. That is how it works. Edge, Chrome, Firefox work roughly the same way. Windows does this as well. This is normal behavior, both Linux and Windows.

To the best of my knowledge, there is not any native way to change this.

If you make the user action to download deliberate, then the pop up appears immediately (in all my experience), so there really should not be an issue.

Comment: Focus stealing is always an anti-pattern, so it's surprising that this cannot be disabled.

Comment: That is how browsers work, so I am not at all surprised. I get the same effect in my Linux machines